# Why am I getting error message: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string when copied from textbook

Tags: sql, string, oracle, insert

I am using oracle 18c and trying to insert info into a row, but keep getting the error message: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string and am using this script:

```
CREATE TABLE acctmanager
(amid CHAR(4),
 amfirst VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amlast VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amedate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
 amsal NUMBER(8,2),
 amcomm NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0,
 region CHAR(2),
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager_amid_pk PRIMARY KEY (amid),
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager_region_ck
     CHECK (region IN ('N', 'NW', 'NE', 'S', 'SE', 'SW', 'W', 'E')));
```

And I am trying to insert: INSERT INTO acctmanager VALUES ('T500', 'NICK', 'TAYLOR', '05-SEPT-09', 42000, 3500, 'NE');

[image]

Comment: `'05-SEP-09'` is a **string**, not a `DATE`. And did you never hear about the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Answer (score 1):

Your date is not a good format. The default format must match that specified in the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. Usually that is 'DD-MON-YY'. Note that is a 3-character month, not 'SEPT'.

If you want to be sure you have a good format (since NLS_DATE_FORMAT can be changed at the session or system level and you shouldn't rely on implicit defaults you can't control), then use the to_date function to to set it explicitly as part of your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO acctmanager VALUES ('T500', 'NICK', 'TAYLOR', TO_DATE('05-SEP-09','DD-MON-YY'), 42000, 3500, 'NE');
```

See here for a list of valid datetime format models:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much for the help and quick reply!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather `TO_DATE('05-SEP-09','DD-MON-RR')` or even better `TO_DATE('05-SEP-2009','DD-MON-YYYY', NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'American')`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that would be even better. My only point was that the choice should be explicit, not left to the implicit default.

Answer (score 0):

Because the date format configured in your Oracle session is different to the configured environment in your textbook.

Try to use this SQL to check the NLS format in your environment first and populate the amedate field using the specified format.

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much for the help and quick reply!